# Trigger Azure pipeline build on GitHub push

Tags: azure-pipelines

I set the `Enabled Continuous Integration` to true and then pushed my commit to my remote repo on GitHub but build did not start. What else I need?
The build can start manually and contains recent updates of my repository, meaning that my connection is valid.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you get the sources? Did you map to the Github repos?

Comment: Yes I did, and used the designer to map, I also update my question to mention that the build can start manually and contains recent repo updates, meaning that I do have a valid connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you need to create a Github [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts) first, and make sure you pushed the changes to the specific branch you have set in `Branch filters` (Branch `18.1` in your scenario).

Tested on my side, everything works as expected.

[image]

Comment: I will accept this answer for now as it seems complete and because CI builds start now (after one day of doing zero changes to my pipeline)